# Jmeter error with version even if PATH are set

Tags: jmeter

Getting this error message below.

```
' java -version 2>&1 | findstr /i "version" is not recognized as an internal     or external command, 
operable program or batch file. 
Not able to find Java executable or version. Please check your Java Installation.
errorlevel=2
```

I have these in PATH but still error is still appear. Any idea?

PATH is already set to

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_45\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

Your path is wrongly configured.

Define it correctly using:

> setenv PATH=%PATH%;Full path to java bin folder

Ensure you put quote around path.

You say it's already define, are you sure there is  a java in the defined place ?

Note you have 2 different versions of Java in path.

Comment: Thanks for reply @UBIK LOAD PACK. I'm on windows and I don't think I need to put quote but I tried it too. It didn't work. I even tried this instructions from http://bluesteel007india.blogspot.com.au/2013/02/setting-up-javahome-and-path.html

Comment: I can also see that java version when I type "java -version" in cmd :(

Answer (score 0):

Issue is not with environment path as java path has been set correctly.

Issue was with broken variable and resolved by resetting broken ComSpec variable.

Run cmd as Admin and reset with command below.

```
setx ComSpec %SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe /m
```